# Load picture in app from local folder

Tags: java

I have inside  my app folder : images folder with images inside  and I have .jar file which I run. I need to load pictures from images folder. I have method which load pictures from URL, I tried  with

```
String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separatorChar+"images"+File.separatorChar+"first.jpg";
try{
URL url=new URL(path);
}
catch(Exception exc){
}
```

but I get error java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /home/images/first.jpg.
What to add like prefix, or is there some better way to load with URL images ?

Comment: Don't catch generic exception ...

Comment: ..and when you do catch exceptions (of any type) don't just ignore them.  Either log them or dump the stacktrace.  Ignoring exceptions is like trying to debug with one arm tied behind your back, blind-folded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a local file the protocol is "file://" however on windows you will need to add an extra "/"

You can specify this at the begining of your URL like this:

```
String path="file:///" + System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separatorChar+"images"+File.separatorChar+"first.jpg";
```

Comment: No, the protocol has only two slashes. Unix paths however often start with another one. In Windows, you need to prefix the drive with an extra slash.

Comment: @OrangeDog  Thanks.  I've updated the anwser with your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to load the picture from an url? Why not load it from a path? which is what you want?

Anyway why don't you try something like:

```
String path= ="file://"+System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separatorChar+"images"+File.separatorChar+"first.jpg";
```

Comment: In windows you will have to add an extra "/" so it will be like "file:///". cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally these images should be inside the jar and loaded via a classloader using `getResource()` or `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: How to do this ? I like this solution, but I don't know how to do this

Comment: I do belive this is a better solution. You have to put the img files insede the jar. (and Pack it) and then call that method. . In eclipse if you put it next to you have files it will pack it.  Check the getResourceAsStream() documentation Don't be lazy :-P

Answer (score 1):

It should be `String path = file://"+ System.get...etc. ~`

But probably it would be better if you load it like with:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResouce("first.png");
```

And you add your images to the classpath.